# Creating sub-sub registry keys in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, registry

I'm using the registry to store some configuration data for an app that I'm working on and I'm struggling to work out how to create sub folders.

Here's an example:

Under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` I've created a folder for my company name and then one of my app like this:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name`

I can create a key within that folder but what I can't seem to do is to create a further folder within it e.g.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/midiDevice`

so that I can store keys relevant to a particular device.  Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/useMidi
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/activeMidiDevice

HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/midiDevice1/
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/midiDevice1/setting1
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/midiDevice1/setting2
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/midiDevice1/setting3

HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/midiDevice2/
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/midiDevice2/setting1
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/midiDevice2/setting2
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Company/App_Name/midiDevice2/setting3
```

Here's my code:

```
' Set flag to indicate that we need to use MIDI to control program and store device name
Dim registryPath As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\App_Name\"
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue(registryPath, "useMidi", True)
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue(registryPath, "activeMidiDevice", deviceName)

' Create device specific path to store settings
registryPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\App_Name\" & deviceName & "\"
Console.WriteLine("Path: " & registryPath)

' Write this to the registry
My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(registryPath)
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue(registryPath, "setting1", value1)
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue(registryPath, "setting2", value2)
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue(registryPath, "setting3", value3)
```

This code just creates all of the keys in the same registry folder: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\App_Name\`

I'm sure this is trivial (and I know from inspecting the registry) it's possible to do but what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I can only imagine that `deviceName` is blank.

Comment: Use the debugger to check the contents of `registryPath` and make sure they're correct.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys - deviceName isn't blank and registryPath is constructed correctly and written out to the console.  That's why I'm at a loss as to why this doesn't work ...

Comment: The key names should not include HKEY_CURRENT_USER, that's already implied by My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.  Other than that, nothing jumps out.

Comment: Thanks for that Hans - are you sure ?  I get an error 'Registry key name must start with valid base key name' if I remove it.